# wpf mahapps theme create items in SplitButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, drop-down-menu, mahapps.metro, split-button

I'm using [wpf mahapps theme](http://mahapps.com/controls/) and I want to create items for a [SplitButton](http://mahapps.com/controls/split_dropdownbutton.html) like so:

```
<Controls:SplitButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,581,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedIndex="1" IsExpanded="True" Background="White">
  <Controls:SplitButton.Items>
          <Button Content="btn" Background="#FFB23E3E"/>
          <MenuItem Background="#FF742323"/>
          <ComboBoxItem Content="cbx" Background="#FFA43131"/>
          <CheckBox Background="#FF8D3535" Content="chk"/>
  </Controls:SplitButton.Items>
</Controls:SplitButton>
```

but when I click on it, nothing happened and I don't know what's wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
<controls:SplitButton ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <controls:SplitButton.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="btn" Background="#FFB23E3E"/>
                <MenuItem Background="#FF742323"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="cbx" Background="#FFA43131"/>
                <CheckBox Background="#FF8D3535" Content="chk"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:SplitButton.ItemTemplate>
</controls:SplitButton>
```

You have to specify `ItemSource` to populate your `ItemTemplate`

Comment: I don't want to bind to ItemSource.

Comment: Edited the answer check if its helpful.

Comment: my desire is when I click the SplitButton, it'll show its items like a combobox so I can select an item. Your solution display all items like a stackpanel and it's not what I really want :(

Comment: Yes you can do that [Check This too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27340082/2470362)